# Finding ACPI Device to Initiate Platform Device for Kernel DMA API

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, dma, acpi

I am trying to perform a DMA operation on my Dell Inspiron 5500 laptop. I would like to transfer, say a Linux page worth (4K on my machine), of data from one physical memory location to another. My questions are as follows

1. How do I determine if I have DMA support for this? I have tried decompiling and parsing /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/DSDT but I am unsure which node maps or would map to a DMA. I am significantly more familiar with device tree blobs in embedded system and this ACPI format is foreign to me
2. If I am able to locate this node, how do I get the

   struct device *dev;

in a platform driver to hand off to

```
struct dma_chan *dma_request_chan(struct device *dev, const char *name);
```

per this guide
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/dmaengine/client.html

**Update**:

Here are links to information files about the system

```
lspci -nk -vv
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/14jNSMAVSuuQIRIBIfGMzAg1pircfX3D-/view?usp=sharing

```
sudo acpidump
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bKWJvFrjv6IQec9VEdw0v_0JLGhpnpZY/view?usp=sharing

```
grep -H 15 /sys/bus/acpi/devices/*/status
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jRh-iQEcK97v4Hi_jKETYLseloL0Avz3/view?usp=sharing

If this is insufficient, I can add dmesg, but it is long since my machine has been running for a long time and I have doing stuff.

Comment: You need to provide much more information about system you are running your stuff on,

Comment: Perhaps I was not so clear about additional info. The platform means almost nothing (marketing name can be the same for very different things), so, what you need is to provide a SoC (In case of x86 possibly CPU / PCH) part number, output of your system logs, like `acpidump -o table.dump` along with `grep -H 15 /sys/bus/acpi/devices/*/status` and `lspci -nk -vv`, perhaps full `dmesg` when your kernel command line has **ignore_loglevel** option set.

Comment: I don't see any general purpose DMA controller available on your machine. For Haswell ULT laptops it may be available under ACPI HID _INTL9C60_. Seems yours is not an ULT variant.